# Ideas for seat reservation with arrays on Java

Tags: java, arrays

As you know, Java's arrays start at zero. When talking about bus seats, you might think about an array of seats. For example, 9 seats.

[Here is a preview of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2iPm.png)

I have a problem with this, because a customer won't ask for seat 0 (the starting one), they'll ask for the "first" seat (seat number one). So, if they input (1) as the desired seat (for the customer it would be the very first one), the method would "reserve" the second array's field, because the very first one is zero. So, I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
public void occupySeat(int seat) {
        Seats[seat] = true;
} /* This is the reservation method
```

What I thought was, well I could just output a message saying that the very first seat they can reserve is zero. And so on. So the last one would be the eighth. But this left me unsatisfied.

Any ideas would be great! Thank you.

Comment: `Seats[seat - 1] = true;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks! But wouldn't that be a problem? Because If a costumer inputs seat number (2) wouldn't it "reserve" field number (1) from the array? Beacause of (seat-1), so it wouldn't really reserve the seat the client asked for

Comment: Java arrays **always** start at `0`, and there is no way to change that. If you want `1` to equal `0` then you are always going to want `n - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common pattern, try

```
public void occupySeat(int seat) {
    Seats[seat-1] = true;
}
```

and maybe make sure that they're entering a valid integer :)

Comment: Thanks! I din't think of that! But I have a problem. Because, suppose the customer picks seat number two. Then it would occupy seat number one because of the (seat-1) operation. And so on. I don't know If I'm explaining myself, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void occupySeat(int seat) {
        Seats[seat-1] = true;
} /* This is the reservation method
```

Just add and subtract 1 as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` instead.

This way you could have more chance for more operations in your collection of seats.

```
private Map<Integer, Seat> seats = new HashMap<>();

public void occupySeat(int seat) {
   seats.put(seat, true);
} /* This is the reservation method
```